# what property can I use to move my colorPicker's popover to display on the left?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-popover

`<input placement="left" class="form-control colorPickerStyle" id="areaColor" name="areaColor" [(colorPicker)]="selectedArea.colour" [style.background]="selectedArea.colour"
                [cpPresetColors]="['#000', '#2889e9', '#e920e9', '#fff500', 'rgba(236,64,64,0.8)']" [cpOKButton]="true" [cpOKButtonClass]="'btn btn-primary btn-xs'"
                [cpCancelButton]="true" [cpCancelButtonClass]="'btn btn-primary btn-xs'" [cpOutputFormat]="'rgba'" (colorPickerChange)="colorChanged($event)"
                [disabled]="!canUpdate && !isNameEditMode" />`
How do I make my colorPicker's popover to display on  left?[image]

Comment: did you try to put align: left; in that code? what version of Bootstrap is this?

Comment: @mlegg this is version 3, i can't use align because this is just a popover that appears on a click to an input field

Comment: you can set popovers left, read this https://www.tutorialrepublic.com/twitter-bootstrap-tutorial/bootstrap-popovers.php read the section Setting the Directions of Popovers